# Mail can't connect to Gmail SMTP server

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, smtp

I recently updated my Mac Pro from Sierra to High Sierra and now Mail cannot connect to the Gmail SMTP server. So I can receive mail but I cannot send. I have found posts from many other users with the same problem and none of the solutions have worked for me. I have tried deleting prefs, deleting my Gmail account in Internet Accounts, turning on and off two step verification, and nothing has worked.

When I run Connection Doctor, I see the following in the error log:

```
WROTE Mar 07 10:32:09.713 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:smtp.gmail.com -- port:465 -- socket:0x6140004a3060 -- thread:0x600000267340
EHLO vuze on mac-pro.home
READ Mar 07 10:32:09.749 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:smtp.gmail.com -- port:465 -- socket:0x6140004a3060 -- thread:0x600000267340
501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "vuze on mac-pro.home" invalid, closing
```

Oddly, when I open terminal the command prompt says "vuze on Mac-Pro:". So this makes me think the problem is something OS or network related, but I have no idea where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: Many people reporting similar issues had luck with identifying as `EHLO localhost` but I'm not sure how to do that in Mac Mail so I'm not posting an answer yet.

Comment: That IS an invalid HELO/EHLO argument.  See the RFC at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821#page-29 . Undo wherever you're setting your hostname to that.

Comment: That's the thing, I haven't set my hostname to "vuze on mac-pro.home" anywhere. I don't know where the "vuze on" part is coming from.